# Getting the frequency of letters in each position

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I have a text file like this example:

```
>chr12:86512-86521
CGGCCAAAG
>chr16:96990-96999
CTTTCATTT
>chr16:97016-97025
TTTTGATTA
>chr16:97068-97077
ATTTAGGGA
```

This file is divided into different parts, and every part has 2 lines. The line which starts with `>` is ID and the 2nd line is a sequence of letters and the letters are `A, T, C or G` and also the length of each sequence is 9 so, for every sequence of letters there are 9 positions. I want to get the frequency of the 4 mentioned letters in every position (we have 9 positions).

Here is the expected output for the small example:

```
one = {'T': 1, 'A': 1, 'C': 2, 'G': 0}
two = {'T': 3, 'A': 0, 'C': 0, 'G': 1}
three = {'T': 3, 'A': 0, 'C': 0, 'G': 1}
four = {'T': 3, 'A': 0, 'C': 1, 'G': 0}
five = {'T': 0, 'A': 1, 'C': 2, 'G': 1}
six  = {'T': 0, 'A': 3, 'C': 0, 'G': 1}
seven = {'T': 2, 'A': 1, 'C': 0, 'G': 1}
eight = {'T': 2, 'A': 1, 'C': 0, 'G': 1}
nine = {'T': 1, 'A': 2, 'C': 0, 'G': 1}
```

I am doing that in Python using the following command. This command has 3 steps. Steps 1 and 2 work fine, but would you help me to improve step 3, which made this pipeline so slow for big files?

## Step 1: to parse the file into a comma-separated file

```
def fasta_to_textfile(filename, outfile): 
    with open(filename) as f, open(outfile, 'w') as outfile:
        header = sequence = None
        out = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=',')
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith('>'):
                if header:
                    entry = header + [''.join(sequence)]
                    out.writerow(entry)
                header = line.strip('>\n').split('|')
                sequence = []
            else:
                sequence.append(line.strip())
        if header:
            entry = header + [''.join(sequence)]
            out.writerow(entry)
```

## Step 2: comma-separated file to a Python dictionary

```
def file_to_dict(filename):
    f = open(filename, 'r')
    answer = {}
    for line in f:
        k, v = line.strip().split(',')
        answer[k.strip()] = v.strip()
    return answer
```

## To print functions from steps 1 and 2:

```
a = fasta_to_textfile('infile.txt', 'out.txt')
d = file_to_dict('out.txt')
```

## Step 3: to get the frequency

```
one=[]
two=[]
three=[]
four=[]
five=[]
six=[]
seven=[]
eight=[]
nine=[]
mylist = d.values()
for seq in mylist:
    one.append(seq[0])
    two.append(seq[1])
    se.append(seq[2])
    four.append(seq[3])
    five.append(seq[4])
    six.append(seq[5])
    seven.append(seq[6])
    eight.append(seq[7])
    nine.append(seq[8])

from collections import Counter
one=Counter(one)    
two=Counter(two)
three=Counter(three)
four=Counter(four)
five=Counter(five)
```

Answer (score 2):

That's a crazy amount of code for such a simple task.  There's no need to generate any intermediate files.  There's no need to create nine separate variables for the nine columns.

To process an input file (whether from `sys.stdin` or as a named argument on the command line), use [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html).  That way, you don't have to hard-code `'infile.txt'`.  Then, simply ignore the lines that start with `>` and strip off the newlines.

To work on columns rather than rows, use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).

### Suggested solution

These seven lines could replace your entire code.

```
import fileinput
from collections import Counter

def nucleotide_lines(f):
    for line in f:
        if not line.startswith('>'):
            yield line.rstrip()

print([Counter(col) for col in zip(*nucleotide_lines(fileinput.input()))])
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add `import csv` and `from collections import Counter`. Probably missed it while copy pasting. Also, your `=` signs are inconsistent in step 3. Try to follow **PEP8**. Also, `a` is useless in this line:

```
a = fasta_to_textfile('infile.txt', 'out.txt')
```

Since you've programmed a void function, `a = None` because it returns nothing.

Is the conversion to the CSV file really necessary? This would be an example of the pipeline:

1. Read the file.
2. Extract the sequence and load it into a N*9 table, where N is the number of sequences
3. Swap the rows and columns (`numpy` can help you out here)
4. A simple `for` loop that uses the `Counter` function on each row (but really column), refactored into less lines. Sadly I don't have time right to rewrite bits of your code right now.

One last thing - are you sure your example is correct? I tried loading it but got: `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)`...